Apache Flink generic deserialization
A specific use case creates the potential for multiple Flik applications consuming json events from different Kafka topics with different schemas but the same business logic. Therefore, I would want a user to be able to define a schema of the json and having a flink job to be aware of this definition to deserialize the incoming messages. There are a couple of approaches but I am unsure which one would be the "most efficient". I've tried creating a generic deserialized object, but this involved a lot of bad practices as generic types were running rampant and caused a lot of overhead with Flink's ser/de engine.
I know that the Table API uses the Row type internally and it's quite flexible. But an implementation like JsonRowDeserializer implements DeserializationSchema<Row> seems silly as JsonRowDeserializationSchema existed and was deprecated.
What is a good way to achieve this, or what datatype can I be deserializing the JSON into so that it's still generic enough to accept schema definitions from external sources?
